# Finding available space for a directory in C# on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, cross-platform, diskspace

I need code that can both compile under Visual Studio & Mono, & run on Linux or Windows.

I need to return the free space available given only the path to the directory.

On windows I'd do something along the lines of -

```
var file  = new FileInfo(path);
var drive = new DriveInfo(file.Directory.Root.FullName);
return drive.AvailableFreeSpace;
```

However on Linux this seems to throw an Argument Exception. file.Directory.Root.FullName returns '/'. DriveInfo throws an Argument Exception of 'The drive name does not exist'

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/iomap/?

Comment: I've read it. I don't see how it would help in this case?

Comment: I think the "The New Solution" section explains how you can launch the application differently which may actually solve the problem.

Comment: case: makes all file system access case insensitive; drive: strips drive name from pathnames.

I don't see how either of those would fix this issue - all it would do is remove the drive letter from windows possibly breaking it there too.

Comment: (I'm trying to find the drive name)

Comment: Hmm, actually i tried your code, and it runs just fine and it returns the free Space of "/"

Comment: OK. Thats odd. Maybe its a permissions issue? We are also running on what is pretty much a live ISO if that makes a difference? - ie an aufs with a ramdisk mounted as the overlay

Comment: OK - it seems to be the live ISO thats causing issue. On a normal debian install the code works fine.

Whereas on the ISO it only works on /lib/live/mount/medium & - /lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs, both of which always return 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the linux df command. This will return you a summary of all available disks on your computer.

```
public static class ServersManager
{      
        public static string GetDiskSpace()
        {
            return string.Join(" ", "df").Bash();
        }

        private static string Bash(this string cmd)
        {
            var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

            var process = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "/bin/bash",
                    Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
            return result;
        }
}
```

The function GetDiskSpace returns a table of the following form:

**Filesystem   |  1K-blocks  |   Used  |  Available  | Use% | Mounted on**

/dev/sda4      |   497240864 |  31182380 | 466058484  |  7%  |    /